# Algorithm to compute a real logarithm of a real matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I would like an algorithm to find the real logarithm of a real matrix.

The existence theorem found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence) is:

> A real matrix has a real logarithm if and only if it is invertible and each Jordan block belonging to a negative eigenvalue occurs an even number of times.

I am working in MATLAB but any adaptable algorithm will do. The example matrix in the following satisfies both conditions.

```
A = [-1 1 0 0; 0 -1 0 0; 0 0 -1 1; 0 0 0 -1];
RealMatrixLogarithm?(A) = X;
```

**EDIT:** I have attempted to understand the algorithm given in [this article](http://scuegypt.edu.eg/ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/morsyIJA1-4-2008.pdf), however it seems to only be valid for normal matrices.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The "special-matrix-logarithm" algorithm computes the logarithm of a 2x2 matrix explicitly. There is an explicit formula, and the algorithm does nothing special except implementing the formula. What part of it don't you understand ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. Thank you for your response. My confusion is how this fits in to the "general-real-logarithm" algorithm and what my input for B and j1 should be.

Comment: The algorithm computes a real Schur decomposition -- it has generally 2x2 blocks in the diagonal, whose logarithm you have to compute at some point.

Comment: In the algorithm, B is in fact T_ii and j_1 is some integer that fixes one determination of the logarithm (if I understand correctly, you have the choice, and you can set it to zero if you want, but I'm not quite sure about it).

Comment: @AlexandreC. Ah I just noticed the comment after the algorithm is given: This works for negative eigenvalues for -normal- matrices, which mine is not. So I guess this algorithm is not useful for my example. Though your comments are helpful should I come across a normal matrix.

Comment: @patrik. I attempted the series expansion but it came up complex, as when I put it in to MATLAB. I thought I'd try here first because I feel like there should be a standard algorithm. I will take your advice if nothing comes up. Cheers.

Comment: If you just want to solve the logarithm in matlab and have noticed that `log` works per element you may want to use the function `logm`. Unless you want to implement the algorithm by yourself. I just wrote this since it took me some time to find out that the matrix function ends with an **m**

Comment: @patrik. Unfortunately logm still comes up complex.

Comment: If logm, is too complex you may have troubles. That function should be quite efficient I guess, even if it may be possible to do better. What problems do you get?

Comment: You can do the series expansion. You can try log(A) = log(2^n A/2^n) = n log2 + log(A/2^n) to put A is as close to identity as possible.

Comment: Another approach is Dunford decomposition: A = D + N where D is semi-simple (diagonalizable in the complex field) and N nilpotent, and DN = ND. Both D and N are real, and one has log(D + N) = log(D) + log(D^{-1}N). Then log D is computable in the real numbers (this is a normal matrix) and the series for log D^{-1} N terminates.

Comment: @patrik. If I logm the matrix in the question it returns to me a matrix with complex numbers in it. I know from the theorem that there must be another solution without any complex numbers, remembering that there may be many solutions to a logarithm. My conundrum is how to find the solution with only real numbers.

Comment: "Dunford decomposition" is called "Jordan-Chevalley decomposition" in the english speaking world

Comment: @Matta Is it really so that it always exist a real solution to the logarithm of a matrix? Note here that the matrix in the example is negatively definite. This means that the matrix have non-positive eigenvalues. In that case, I do not think that there is a real solution to the logarithm of a matrix. Intuitively this should be similar to calculating the logarithm of a negative number. Further in the series expansion on wikipedia, this seems to be the case as well.

Comment: @patrik. See the theorem in the question.

Comment: Answered in the OP's [Math.StackExchange.com version of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1272847/80812) –which was probably a better site for this question.

Comment: @horchler. I concede that getting the specific answer for that matrix was a mathematical question, but I am still unsatisfied because I would like to have a general answer to this problem for all real matrices. My question is: How do I find the real logarithm of a real matrix? I feel that the answer will be some algorithm. Is that a question for this site or for maths stack? If you think the latter then I will ask it on there. In my head I thought 'algorithm = stack overflow', but I see that that may be a misconception.